# Length of the line in a file in Python returns value always as No. of Characters + 1

Tags: python

I am using python 2.7.x
I have a file page06.txt

```
1
22
333
4444
55555
666666
7777777
88888888
```

I am reading this file through a program:

```
from __future__ import print_function
fileobj = open("page06.txt")
i = 0
while True:
    F = fileobj.readline()
    print("::::", len(F))
    if len(F) <= 0:
        break;
    print(F , end="")
fileobj.close()
```

The first line contains 1, so as per my understanding is that len(F) must return 1 but it returns 2.
So, whyis the length of all the lines in the file always is

```
"No. of characters" +1
```

Comment: There is a newline character for each line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You counted also the new line. Use `F = fileobj.readline().strip()` to get the line without the new line character.

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the invisible newline (`\n`) character in each line with the `.strip()` function

In addition, instead of using infinite while loops you can simplify your code using a `for loop` and `with open`(this closes your file automatically):

```
from __future__ import print_function
with open("page06.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        print("::::", len(line.strip()))
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a newline character for each line. In addition, your method for reading the file is very inefficient and redundant with your while loop and read line calls. Try using a with statement:

```
with open('test.txt') as test:
    for line in test: print(len(line.rstrip()))
```

Alternatively, you can split the entire file by the newlines and then print the length of each line:

```
with open('test.txt') as test:
    lengths = [len(i) for i in test.read().split('\n')]
    for length in lengths: print(length)
```